# Good way to deal with comma separated values in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, tokenize

I am getting passed comma separated values to a stored procedure in oracle.  I want to treat these values as a table so that I can use them in a query like:

```
select * from tabl_a where column_b in (<csv values passed in>)
```

What is the best way to do this in 11g?

Right now we are looping through these one by one and inserting them into a gtt which I think is inefficient.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves exactly same problem

[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not come with a built-in tokenizer.  But it is possible to roll our own, using SQL Types and PL/SQL.  I have posted a sample solution in [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635930/sql-query-to-translate-a-list-of-numbers-matched-against-several-ranges-to-a-lis/2636842#2636842).

That would enable a solution like this:

```
select * from tabl_a 
where column_b in ( select * 
                    from table (str_to_number_tokens (<csv values passed in>)))
/
```

Comment: but in that solution you never show what `str_to_number_tokens` looks like?

Comment: @dmitry - Perhaps I was too subtle but there is a link embedded in the sentence "I am using a variant of Anup Pani's implementation," i.e. http://anuppani.blogspot.com/2007/07/tokenizer-in-oracle-plsql.html

Answer (score 0):

In 11g you can use the "occurrence" parameter of REGEXP_SUBSTR to select the values directly in SQL:

```
select regexp_substr(<csv values passed in>,'[^,]+',1,level) val
from   dual
connect by level < regexp_count(<csv values passed in>,',')+2;
```

But since regexp_substr is somewhat expensive I am not sure if it is the most effective in terms of being the fastest.