# Split column to multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, tokenize

I have table with a column that contains multiple values separated by comma (,) and would like to split it so I get earch Site on its own row but with the same Number in front.

So my select would from this input

```
table Sitetable

Number             Site
952240             2-78,2-89                                                                                                                                                                      
952423             2-78,2-83,8-34
```

Create this output

```
Number             Site
952240             2-78
952240             2-89
952423             2-78 
952423             2-83
952423             8-34
```

I found something that I thought would work but nope..

```
select Number, substr(
    Site, 
    instr(','||Site,',',1,seq),
    instr(','||Site||',',',',1,seq+1) - instr(','||Site,',',1,seq)-1)  Site
from Sitetable,(select level seq from dual connect by level <= 100) seqgen
where instr(','||Site,',',1,seq+1) > 0
```

Edit2: I see that I have actually had a part working select all the time (I was a crappy tester :(), the above one works but the only problem is that it looses the last Site value but Ill try to work a bit on that..

Edit3: Now its working

```
select Number, substr(
Site, 
instr(','||Site,',',1,seq),
instr(','||Site||',',',',1,seq+1) - instr(','||Site,',',1,seq)-1)  Site
from Sitetable,(select level seq from dual connect by level <= 100) seqgen
where instr(','||Site,',',1,seq) > 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to translate a list of numbers matched against several ranges, to a list of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635930/sql-query-to-translate-a-list-of-numbers-matched-against-several-ranges-to-a-lis)

Comment: Check out my answer to the other SO post I identified as a possible duplicate.  It is a 10g solution to your problem.

Comment: I think I got my select to work a bit better now

Comment: is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2008??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the correct answer is.

```
select Number, substr(
Site, 
instr(','||Site,',',1,seq),
instr(','||Site||',',',',1,seq+1) - instr(','||Site,',',1,seq)-1)  Site
from Sitetable,(select level seq from dual connect by level <= 100) seqgen
where instr(','||Site,',',1,seq) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you Try Michael Sofaer's answer to [How to best split csv strings in oracle 9i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089508/how-to-best-split-csv-strings-in-oracle-9i)

```
create or replace function splitter_count(str in varchar2, delim in char) return int as
val int;
begin
  val := length(replace(str, delim, delim || ' '));
  return val - length(str); 
end;

create type token_list is varray(100) of varchar2(200);

CREATE or replace function tokenize (str varchar2, delim char) return token_list as
ret token_list;
target int;
i int;
this_delim int;
last_delim int;
BEGIN
  ret := token_list();
  i := 1;
  last_delim := 0;
  target := splitter_count(str, delim);
  while i <= target
  loop
    ret.extend();
    this_delim := instr(str, delim, 1, i);
    ret(i):= substr(str, last_delim + 1, this_delim - last_delim -1);
    i := i + 1;
    last_delim := this_delim;
  end loop;
  ret.extend();
  ret(i):= substr(str, last_delim + 1);
  return ret;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

**------------Create Result Table-------------------------------------------**

create table resulTable(

cnumber number,

Site varchar2(1000)

);

**------------Create Splitter Procedure--------------------------------------**

*/*Here I replaced numbers for example:  2-78 by s2ss78s for using

DBMS_UTILITY.comma_to_table(it doesn't work on numbers)*/*

create or replace procedure split_list_to_rows(num number,plist varchar2) as

ptablen BINARY_INTEGER;

ptab DBMS_UTILITY.uncl_array;

begin

DBMS_UTILITY.comma_to_table (

list => replace(replace(CONCAT('s', plist),',',',s'),'-','ss'),

tablen => ptablen,

tab => ptab);

FOR i IN 1 .. ptablen LOOP

insert INTO  resulTable VALUES (num,replace(ltrim(ptab(i),'s'),'ss','-'));

END LOOP;

END;

**------------PL/SQL Block To Execute Procedure For Each Row-------------------**

begin

for i in (select cnumber,Site from Sitetable)

loop

split_list_to_rows(i.cnumber,i.Site);

end loop;

end;

**------------------------See The Result---------------------------------------**

select * from resulTable;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a max limit of 100 comma separated values which is unnecessary, though probably not harmful in your case.

instead of

```
from Sitetable,(select level seq from dual connect by level <= 100)
```

this should work for any number of values (level limited by the max number of commas present).

```
from Sitetable,(select level seq from dual connect by level <=  (select max((LENGTH(site)-LENGTH(REPLACE(site,',', '' ))) + 1) from sitetable)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use cross join:

SELECT Number, SiteNumber
FROM Sitetable
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Site, ',');