# to select multiple value from one row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that looks like this

```
A 1,2 
B 3,4,5
```

And I want to produce a result set that looks like this:

```
A 1 
A 2 
B 3 
B 4
B 5
```

Is there a SQL statement that will do this? I am using Oracle.

Comment: I don't understand your table. What does a comma mean? A new row? What does a space mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split column to multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713107/split-column-to-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 1):

```
create table foo (
  var1 varchar2(1),
  var2 varchar2(15)
);
insert into foo (var1, var2) values ('A', '1,2');
insert into foo (var1, var2) values ('B', '3,4,5');
insert into foo (var1, var2) values ('C', '6');

-- This will work if you are using oracle 11g
-- otherwise you will need to *guess* at the max number of rows
select var1, var2
  from (
      select var1
           , substr(var2
                    , instr(var2, ',', 1, l.appearance)+1
                    , instr(var2, ',', 1, l.appearance+1) - instr(var2, ',', 1, l.appearance)-1) var2
        from (select var1, ','||var2||',' var2 from foo)
           , (select level appearance 
                from dual
          connect by level - 1 <= (select max(regexp_count(var2, ',')) from foo)) l
        ) 
    where var2 is not null
order by var1, var2;

-- This will work if you are using oracle 10g
select var1, var2
  from (
      select var1
           , substr(var2
                    , instr(var2, ',', 1, l.appearance)+1
                    , instr(var2, ',', 1, l.appearance+1) - instr(var2, ',', 1, l.appearance)-1) var2
        from (select var1, ','||var2||',' var2 from foo)
           , (select level appearance 
                from dual
          connect by level - 1 <= 99) l
        ) 
    where var2 is not null
order by var1, var2;
```