# How to generate Multi-row for each row in a table using SQL only

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split column to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713107/split-column-to-multiple-rows)

i have table contains the following data:-

```
Name
---------
mouse,keyboard,screen
harddisk,cable
processor
```

I need to create query to retrieve the data from this table to be as follow:-

```
Name
--------
mouse
keyboard
screen
harddisk
cable
processor
```

Comment: What RDBMS? Hopefully you want this query so you can normalize the database?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a split function like: http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

Then you can run:

```
  select *
  from MyTable t
  cross apply dbo.Split(t.name) s
```

and s.items will contain what you want.

Comment: Instead of custom split function you can use CTE for SQL Server 2005+. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: True, but I think the loop might be more performant. Recursive CTEs have a limit to how many levels of recursion are supported etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I need the solution in oracle not sql server

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713107/split-column-to-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE (Item VARCHAR(64))
    DECLARE @spot SMALLINT, @str VARCHAR(8000), @sql VARCHAR(8000), @cslist VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT @cslist = mouse + ',' + keyboard,screen + ',' + harddisk + ',' + cable + ',' + processor
FROM Table

        WHILE @cslist <> ''  
        BEGIN  
            SET @spot = CHARINDEX(',', @cslist)

            IF @spot > 0  
                BEGIN  
                    SET @str = LEFT(@cslist, @spot - 1)  
                    SET @cslist = RIGHT(@cslist, LEN(@cslist) - @spot)  
                END  
            ELSE  
                BEGIN  
                    SET @str = @cslist  
                    SET @cslist = ''  
                END  
            INSERT @t SELECT @str

    SELECT * FROM @t
```