# How to split the columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
Name            Nameid
P,q,r,s,t       One
A,b,c           Two
D,e             Three
```

This is my source table, but i want my target table like this

```
Name    Nameid
P       One
Q       One
R       One
S       One
T       One
A       Two
B       Two
C       Two
D       three
```

Comment: spit columns?  sometimes I wish I could spit columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split column to multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713107/split-column-to-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, I think it would be more elegant to store the data in a different way.

If you are inserting your rows from a program, try splitting your string there, and insert a few more rows instead.

Let me give you a pseudo code example.

```
number = "One"
many_letters = "P,Q,R,S,T".split(",")
for(letter in many_letters) {
     insert_values(letter, number)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what he asked. The question is vague though.

Comment: You're right. I'm thinking it is a potential solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, lifted from [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2189860818012#50703914895102):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (name VARCHAR2(20), nameid VARCHAR2(10));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('P,q,r,s,t','One');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('A,b,c'    ,'Two');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('D,e'      ,'Three');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT     nameid
  2  ,          REGEXP_SUBSTR (name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS token
  3  FROM       t
  4  CONNECT BY PRIOR nameid = nameid
  5  AND        REGEXP_INSTR (name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) > 0
  6  AND        PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('p', 10) IS NOT NULL
  7  ;

NAMEID     TOKEN
---------- --------------------
One        P
One        q
One        r
One        s
One        t
Three      D
Three      e
Two        A
Two        b
Two        c

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry I didn't understand the question it was posted. It's been reformatted since.

Oracle does not have a built in Split function, which is what you need here. The following link shows how to create a custom Split function:

http://srinisreeramoju.blogspot.com/2010/03/oracle-custom-split-function.html

Once you've created the types and the function you would simply call it as:

```
SELECT
    Split(Name, ',') AS Name,
    NameID
FROM
    YourTable
```